# How do you do arbitrary precision calculations in Julia?

Tags: julia, probability

I come from a Python background and an important point using Python’s Decimal module for arbitrary precision calculations is knowing when you do and don’t have to specify numbers of type Decimal in, for example, probability calculations.

**How often** do you have to specify arbitrary precision types for numbers in a Julia calculation?

I learn best by examples and the example I want to solve follows.

Calculate the probability of at least one success when randomly sampling without replacement a bucket of 26 ABC to Z blocks 26!, 3(26)!, and 5(26)! times.

**Given:**

Success on one trial = randomly drawing the blocks out in the correct order: A, B, C, to Z.

The number of random trials is n = 26! or 3n or 5n.

The probability of success on one random trial, p = 1/n

The probability of failure on one random trial is f = 1 – p.

**Calculate** (using type specification **as little** as necessary):

The confidence level, CL, of at least one success in n trials using CL = 1 – f^n

The CL for 3n trials using CL = 1 - f^(3n)

The CL for 5n trials using CL = 1 - f^(5n)

Comment: I'm wondering if this "question" is on-topic for SO.  There is no, “I would like others to explain ______ to me”.  In addition, there is no _actual_ problem to be solved.  I wonder if _presentations_ like this are better suited in a blog or someplace like [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code).

Comment: @rickhg12hs Your point is well-taken.  I have redone both the question and the answer per your comment.  Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Do you still find the question and answer objectionable after my edits?  Being new to Julia I truly did not expect the arbitrary precision calculations to work so easily based on my experience with the Python Decimal module.  It seems that others may also not realize how well Julia's type inference works when applied to these kind of calculations.  I have never had a blog.  Any suggestions for where/how to host a Julia-related programming blog.

Comment: I hope users are reading Julia's documentation.  There is a section on [Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic-1). Perhaps as a goal, you can contribute to [juliabloggers.com](https://www.juliabloggers.com/julia-bloggers-submit-feed/).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julia works very well at flowing the "big" number type specification through the calculations.
For example, in the following code I only specify one number as big"26", everything else is automatic.

I have just started using Julia, but have been doing arbitrary precision calculations in various ways for years.  Julia provides, hands-down, the most pleasant experience with this kind of thing I have ever had.

```
# Set precision to 150 bits which should be adequate precision.
setprecision(150)

# Note that we only have to specify a "big" number here.
n = factorial(big"26")
println("n = factorial(big\"26\") = ", n)
println("Note that we never have to use \"big\" again in the following code.")
println("typeof(n) = ", typeof(n), "\n")  

# p is the probability of success on 1 trial.
p = 1/n
println("p = 1/n = ", p)
# Note we did not have to specify the type of p.
println("typeof(p) = ", typeof(p), "\n")

# f is the probability of failure on 1 trial.
f = 1 - p
println("f = 1 - p = ", f)
println("typeof(f) = ", typeof(f), "\n")   

# CL is the probability of at least 1 success in n trials.
# CL stands for confidence level.   
CL = 1 - f^n
println("The 63% CL for n trials = 1 - f^n = ", CL)
println("typeof(CL) = ", typeof(CL), "\n")   

# Here is the 95% conf. level using 3n random trials.
CL95 = 1 - f^(3n)
println("The 95% CL for 3n trials = ", CL95)
println("typeof(CL95) = ", typeof(CL95), "\n")

# Here is the 99% conf. level using 5n random trials.
CL99 = 1 - f^(5n)
println("The 99% CL for 5n trials = ", CL99)
println("typeof(CL99) = ", typeof(CL99), "\n")

""" ============================= Output ==============================
n = factorial(big"26") = 403291461126605635584000000
Note that we never have to use "big" again in the following code.
typeof(n) = BigInt

p = 1/n = 2.4795962632247974600749435458479566174226555415e-27
typeof(p) = BigFloat

f = 1 - p = 9.9999999999999999999999999752040373677520254001e-01
typeof(f) = BigFloat

The 63% CL for n trials = 1 - f^n = 6.3212055882855767839219205578358958187929158048e-01
typeof(CL) = BigFloat

The 95% CL for 3n trials = 9.5021293163213605701567013782477488392169554992e-01
typeof(CL95) = BigFloat

The 99% CL for 5n trials = 9.9326205300091453290223898909666750856240017783e-01
typeof(CL99) = BigFloat
"""
```

Comment: # Set the precision to 300 bits for plenty of precision. But you only set the precision for 150 bits?? setprecision(150) Is this a mistake???

Comment: Good catch Steven!  Thanks for pointing it out.  My comment does not match the code and I need to check the implications.   Thanks again for your careful look at this code.  I hate to make mistakes, but that is one.  However, I do not think it will change any results.  I will respond when I have done some tests.

Comment: @StevenSiew I edited the comment per your good catch and checked the code by running a script version.  Things check Okay.  Thanks again!  If you see any other problems or have questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Precision Decimal Floating Point like the Decimal in Python, I have written one myself. You can set the decimal precision to any positive integer value. Contact me if you want a copy of the module.

```
julia> factorial(BigInt(26))
403291461126605635584000000

julia> println("How many decimal digits do we need?")
How many decimal digits do we need?

julia> length(string(  factorial(BigInt(26))  ))
27

julia> using PDFPs

julia> PDFP_setDefaultPrecision(40)
40

julia> n = PDFP(    factorial(BigInt(26))    )
PDFP(0, 26, [4, 0, 3, 2, 9, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1, 2, 6, 6, 0, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 8, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

julia> disp(a::PDFP) = println(PDFP_toShortCommonString(a))
disp (generic function with 1 method)

julia> p = 1/n
PDFP(0, -27, [2, 4, 7, 9, 5, 9, 6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 4, 7, 9, 7, 4, 6, 0, 0, 7, 4, 9, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 8, 4, 7, 9, 5, 6, 6, 1, 7, 4, 2, 2])

julia> disp(p)
2.47960E-27

julia> println("Let's call failure q as per convention in probability questions")
Let's call failure q as per normal in probability questions

julia> q = 1 - p
PDFP(0, -1, [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 7, 3, 6, 7, 7, 5, 2])

julia> disp(q)
1.00000

julia> PDFP_toFortranString(q)
"9.999999999999999999999999975204037367752E-1"

julia> at_least_one_success_in_n_trials = 1 - q^n
PDFP(0, -1, [6, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 5, 5, 8, 8, 2, 8, 5, 5, 8, 0, 5, 5, 6, 0, 2, 0, 5, 7, 9, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 0, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 9])

julia> disp(at_least_one_success_in_n_trials)
0.632121

julia> at_least_one_success_in_3n_trials = 1 - q^(3*n)
PDFP(0, -1, [9, 5, 0, 2, 1, 2, 9, 3, 1, 6, 3, 2, 1, 3, 6, 2, 1, 0, 1, 6, 5, 3, 1, 1, 5, 3, 8, 4, 6, 6, 4, 3, 9, 0, 4, 8, 2, 9, 1, 0])

julia> disp(at_least_one_success_in_3n_trials)
0.950213

julia> at_least_one_success_in_5n_trials = 1 - q^(5*n)
PDFP(0, -1, [9, 9, 3, 2, 6, 2, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 9, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 6, 4, 3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 7, 4, 8, 6, 8, 9, 6, 2, 8, 1])

julia> disp(at_least_one_success_in_5n_trials)
0.993262
```

Comment: Thanks for your generous offer Steven!  How should I contact you?

Comment: Send me email at StevenSiew2@gmail.com

Comment: An email should be on the way.

Comment: Why not make it a package and put it on github?

Comment: Because: 1. I haven't finish doing all the test cases. 2. I have no idea how to make a package. 3. I have never used Github in my life 4. Code in not optimised

Answer (score 0):

You can define by using
`setprecision(n)`, where n is the precision you want.

Then, use `BigFloat` to define the variables.

Finally, `using Printf` to display the digits.

See an example in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot of the terminal]