# Calculate and display huge fibonaci numbers

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I'm pretty new to programming in general (just started uni), and can't find an answer (or maybe know to little to spot it) to my problem.

A few months ago I saw this video about a dynamic algorithm for calculating fibonaci numbers and just now I decided to try if I can do that myself. I have the algorithm (or as close to a proper one I could make on my own), but I don't know how to calculate and display HUGE numbers. 20 Digits is far too small. I'd like to try and go above the 200th fibonaci number, which is even larger than a 128bit integer can handle.

Here is my Code so far:

```
unsigned long long int dynFib(int n){

    unsigned long long int lastTwo[2] = {0,1};
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned long long int fib = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){

        fib = lastTwo[0] + lastTwo[1];
        lastTwo[counter] = fib;
        counter = 1 - counter;
    }

    return fib;
}
```

I'd assume that some very large modifications would have to made, to actually get the result I'd like, I don't have a clue what those are though.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: You may need to use strings for representing numbers. Or a library that handles big integers.

Comment: There is no built in support for arbitrarily large integers in C++, you need a third party library for that. For example GMP or MPIR. However installing and using third party libraries is not something I'd recommend for a beginner learning C++.

Comment: Implementing addition for numbers in strings "like on paper" shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: However representing your integers as strings (as @kiner_shah suggests) is something that a beginner could try.

Comment: Represent integers as vectors of integers, then implement the addition algorithm you were taught when you were little. You could use a library but it's good practice to implement your own, and you're probably going to to it at uni anyway. (Search for "arbitrary precision arithmetic" or "bignum".)

Comment: @kiner_shah Now that you say that, it makes sense. I'll try to see how I'd have to modify the math to do that. I guess I'll have to creat some form of string array, iterate through the number, add 19 (or less) digits together, save them in the array as string and repeat until I'm at the end. Then display them in the proper order. Guess I was right with the huge modifications. :D

Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ohh that sounds like an interesting approach as well. I haven't done anything with vectors yet. (I'm assuming they are similar to arrays?)

I'll try both yours and the string approach. Can't hurt to have tried both. Thank you :D

Comment: Depending on how big you want to go and why your best bet might be a scratchpad algebra system like Maxima which will pretty much do it for you out of the tin or a language with native support for large precision integers or arbitrary precision floating point. [Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376502/) springs to mind as one candidate for this sort of problem but Python also has some large number support as well. The old x87 BCD arithmetic instructions will let you do up to 18 decimal digits at a time and with easy conversion to ASCII strings if you are prepared to use them.

Comment: Besides the aforementioned options, if you are compiling with clang, you could use `_BitInt(4096)` for a 4096-bit integer. Maybe you don't need infinite precision, just a lot of bits.

Comment: Hey @Jaeric, I just happened to have worked very recently on this topic. I have release a small bigint library in this [Github repository](https://github.com/AtmoFX/bigint) and it just so happens to carry an implementation of Fibonacci sequences with detailed documentation. No guarantee (yet) it is bug free but you may want to check. It can go quite far: I personally went to Fibonacci(500000) (about 104k digits, 300ms to calculate) or 1000000! (about 5.5 million digits, 10mins to calculate). The library also supports generalizations of the Fib sequence. Let me know if you have any question.